# Htaccess redirect remove part of url if contains certain string

Tags: .htaccess

How can I change my url from /images/hold/... to /hold/...

I have this but it doesnt work:

```
RewriteRule ^/images/hold/(.*) /hold/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/images/hold/(.*) /hold/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

In per-directory `.htaccess` files the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` directive never starts with a slash. So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^images/hold/(.*) /hold/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Or, to cut out some repetition:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(hold/.*) /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If you've been experimenting with 301 redirects then you may need to clear your browser cache, as these get cached hard by the browser.